# API Authorization Google sheets API

Tags: google-sheets-api

I have a client email that ends with .gserviceaccount.com. I was told I have to share this email with my google sheets. I cant however. It says that it cannot share sheets to emails outside of the organization. Is there another way to connect to my Google sheets besides sharing with the client email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your sheet's sharing settings, and share it to anyone with the link. Then give the link to the user with a service account that's not in your organization.

However, your organization's admin might have your sharing settings restricted to only users within your org.

**Note that:** A service account is a special kind of account used by an application or a virtual machine (VM) instance, not a person.

#### Further reading:

- [What are service accounts ?](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts?_ga=2.262483660.-1960079975.1580112773#what_are_service_accounts)
- [Differences between a service account and a user account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts?_ga=2.262483660.-1960079975.1580112773#differences_between_a_service_account_and_a_user_account)

Comment: Lets say my adming has the sharing settings to users within the organization only, then what can i do to share the sheet with the api client email?

Comment: You have to get permission from your admin. He has to allow you to share it with users outside your org. Otherwise you are trying to do something forbidden with your data.